# Error: AVD not created

Tags: android-virtual-device, avd-manager

```
bruno@ubuntu:/opt/android/android-sdk-linux$ sdkmanager --list
Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...             
  Path                                    | Version      | Description                    | Location                                
  -------                                 | -------      | -------                        | -------                                 
  build-tools;24.0.3                      | 24.0.3       | Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.3 | build-tools/24.0.3/                     
  emulator                                | 27.2.9       | Android Emulator               | emulator/                               
  ndk-bundle                              | 17.0.4754217 | NDK                            | ndk-bundle/                             
  patcher;v4                              | 1            | SDK Patch Applier v4           | patcher/v4/                             
  platform-tools                          | 27.0.1       | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools/                         
  platforms;android-24                    | 2            | Android SDK Platform 24        | platforms/android-24/                   
  system-images;android-24;default;x86_64 | 8            | Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image | system-images/android-24/default/x86_64/
  tools                                   | 26.1.1       | Android SDK Tools              | tools/
```

I get this error on create `avd`:

```
bruno@ubuntu:/opt/android/android-sdk-linux$ avdmanager create avd -n bruno -k "system-images;android-24;default;x86_64" --device "Nexus 5" --sdcard 100M
Auto-selecting single ABI x86_64========] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
Parsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.3/package.xmlParsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/emulator/package.xmlParsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/package.xmlParsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/patcher/v4/package.xmlParsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/package.xmlParsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-24/package.xmlParsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linuxError: AVD not created.24/default/x86_64/package.xmlParsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/package.xmlCopying files                                                                   
null
```

my java

```
bruno@ubuntu:/opt/android/android-sdk-linux$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue, the error you get isn't very helpful but the bottom line is that you need to install some more things using the sdkmanager before creating the avd.

Split up the error you get and you'll see this:

```
Parsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/**build-tools**/24.0.3/package.xml
Parsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/**emulator**/package.xml
Parsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/**ndk-bundle**/package.xml
Parsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/**patcher/v4**/package.xml
Parsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/**platform-tools**/package.xml
Parsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/**platforms/android-24**/package.xml
Parsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linuxError: AVD not created.24/default/x86_64/package.xml
Parsing /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/**tools**/package.xml
Copying files                                                                   
null
```

Now run `sdkmanager --list` to list all available packages.

If you are missing anything from the error output, install it. I.e.

```
sdkmanager "build-tools:24.0.3"
sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
sdkmanager "platform-tools"
sdkmanager "platforms;android-24"
sdkmanager "tools"
```

and so on...

Comment: How do you "split up" the error? I could handle the situation using verbose mode, which hinted on how to progress: `avdmanager -v create avd ...`

Answer (score -1):

After deleting an avd that was still runner, my machine got into a state where `avdmanager create avd` would respond with "Error: AVD not created".

The easiest solution I found was to run:

`mv ~/.android ~/android_backup`

Once verified that no data is lost, the android_backup dir can be removed.